# using the verb appreciate

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

His art collection appreciated greatly over a period of thirty years.

I am wondering the reason why the verb *appreciate* has not been used as following:

It would be appreciated...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Appreciate* has both transitive and intransitive uses.

- As a transitive verb (which is required if you cast the sentence in the passive voice, *be appreciated*, as in your rewrite) it has a range of meanings: 'value, recognize or assess the value of, be grateful for'.
- As in intransitive verb (which is how it is used in your first example) it means 'increase in value'.

  > His art collection appreciated greatly *means the value of his collection increased*.

Comment: Sir, since it uses 'over the period of years', shouldn't be there 'has been/had been'?

Comment: @MaulikV Only if you are adopting a standpoint (a Reference Time) at the end of the period from which you look back at the period. The sentence might appear in a narrative with a 'running' RT: "In the 1940s he bought the works of then unknown artists like Pollock and de Kooning. Over the next thirty years his collection appreciated; by the 70s it was worth several million dollars."